# Pandas/SQLalchemy merge dataframe and table

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

On one hand I have a database with a table which looks like :

```
id fruit  color  provider
1  apple  red    foo
2  apple  green  bar
3  apple  green  toto
3  melon  yellow tata
```

On the other hand I have a pandas dataframe looking like that :

```
fruit  color
apple  green
melon  orange
orange orange
```

I wanted to do a merge on the table and the dataframe to have this output :

```
color fruit provider
apple green bar
apple green toto
```

How can I do my sqlalchemy query to filter on fruit and color from my dataframe ?

NB: since my table is very big I can't retrieve all as df and then merge df.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`pandas.read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) read sql as parameters `con` is a `SQLAlchemy connectable`.

```
df = pd.read_sql(sql, con)
```

---

method1: construct a SQL to query...

```
append_str = '\n or '.join(df.apply(lambda x: f"(fruit = '{x.fruit}' and color = '{x.color}')", axis=1).tolist())

sql = '''
select color, fruit, provider
from tb_name
where %s
''' % append_str

print(sql)

    select color, fruit, provider
    from tb_name
    where (fruit = 'apple' and color = 'green')
     or (fruit = 'melon' and color = 'orange')
     or (fruit = 'orange' and color = 'orange')
```

---

method2:

import the df to database and use SQL directly.

```
df.to_sql('df_table', conn)
sql = '''
select t1.color, t1.fruit, t1.provider
from tb_name t1
inner join df_table t2
    on t1.fruit = t2.fruit and t1.color = t2.color
'''
```

Comment: Is there a easier way using the sqlachemy  session and query ?

Comment: `pandas.read_sql` can read sql directly, as sqlachemy engine as con.

Comment: I modify my request to do a join between tables instead of constructing my df and then i use read_sql and it works fine thanks you